# Manage Tags for entries of the website with JS and PHP

Tags: php, tags

In my webiste, I classify all my entries by categories, wich its becoming a little confusing as I have like 3.000 entries now.

so, I need to implement tags.

I know all the website use them now, wordpress and everything.. I have been google'ing for a real while... is there a built in script (or almost) to manage tags? (insert tags, list tags, top tags,.)

I mean, there has to be any utility that can help me with this..  do you know any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't found a script probably because using tags is quite simple :)
I have implemented tags into one of my projects using the "Scuttle" solution in the next link:
http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you!,

After reading it.. i have one question, why in the same table?  

If i  had to do it, i was thinking to do it with 2 tables, one for articles, and one for tags. i though this way it will be easier to get: popular tags and so on...

And also, this way, how can you know many tags you have? and how many repeticions?

Thanks! looks like almost done

Comment: the "Scuttle" solution uses two tables..one for your entries and one for the tags...as you've said, it is easier to get statistics on your tags, the list of tags, etc.

Comment: btw, for the scuttle sollution, scroll a little bit down the page...

Answer (score 0):

Treat your categories as tags now.

If your categories are not poly-hierarchical, then consider making them so.

(eg an article could appear in more than one category)